# NodeJS MySQL ORM with composite primary keys and specific VARCHAR lengths

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm

I've been looking for a MySQL ORM for Node.  I've looked into [persist.js](https://github.com/jeremydurham/persist-js), [sequelize](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://www.sequelizejs.com/&ei=Cc9tUJvBJIr1iQKi_4GYAw&usg=AFQjCNEiUxMG4RhBsZ18f7powg0nIC4TQg), and [node-orm](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm). Unfortunately none of them support two features that I require:
1. support for composite primary keys (most only support the "id" field as the primary key)
2. the ability to specify my VARCHAR length

I have a table with millions of rows that uses a VARCHAR(16). Upping that to 255 will add hundreds of MB of wasted space to the db. That table will continue to grow too, further contributing to the waste.

Are there any alternatives out there that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

node-orm has a advanced options now .

see here: [node-rom2/advanced-options](http://dresende.github.io/node-orm2/#advanced-options), so I think you can change primary id now. :)

Comment: You can now specify your VARCHAR length, but it still doesn't look like they support composite primary keys. They just let you specify a different field as the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Look at pair: [mysql](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql) and [light-orm](https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm)
Mysql has native implementation - fast, light-orm is wrapped around relational dbs.

Comment: I see you wrote light-orm. How do you create composite primary keys on models?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late answer here :) Objection.js does support composite keys (http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/#composite-keys) and creating mysql varchar columns shouldn't be up to ORM.